# XML Parsing need help iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

How do you get "MayurS123" from following xml tag by parsing?

```
<eletitle lnk="http://192.168.10.2/justmeans/trunk/newsfeed/mayurs">MayurS123 Sharma</eletitle>
```

My file is getting parsed properly. Here I'm able to retrieve the lnk component by doing:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"eletitle"])
{
        aGoodwork.lnk = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"lnk"];
}
```

But I'm not getting how to get in actual title.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Look at any of the XML parsing examples Apple provides with the iPhone SDK and you'll find appropriate code samples.

Comment: And remember, this method may called several times, so you have to collect the found characters and save them in "didEndElement"